# How to Repair IMEI of rooted phone without backup

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.4-kitkat, backup, imei

I recently rooted my Samsung Galaxy S2 AT&T phone (SGH-I777) with KitKat AOCP version. I used ClockworkMod 6.0.4.6 recovery. However, I encountered a problem "E: Cant mount storage/sdcard0" . I formatted my sdcard0 and then it worked.

However, in this process I deleted my efs folder which supposed to have the IMEI information. Hence, now the phone can not get telephone service, so I can not call.

I have gone through the forums explaining how to restore IMEI if you have a backup, or how to edit a corrupted imei file. However, I coudn't find a suitable solution for my case.I don't have anything inside my efs folder to start with.

I know my EMEI number, since its written on the back of my phone. Is there any way I can generate a fresh IMEI file for my phone from the number. What steps I need to follow to get my phone running again.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a way to hexedit your IMEI back in, but only if you manage to regen the efs folder...

Comment: The efs folder is created by the custom rom. But the file which holds the imei info: "nv_data.bin" is empty. If I can get a sample file, may be I will be able to edit it with my IMEI number.